# Why does the pattern only appear on last Canvas element?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to allow the ability to change texture of the shape so basically i am redrawing based on the values of shade object. However the outline of the shade that gets rendered onto the canvas elements work on ALL canvases however when setting an image into the shade object the code only renders on the last canvas? Why and how can i get around this?

https://jsfiddle.net/cbchrL1g/

```
Code is in the jsfiddle link please check
```

Comment: in your for loop (while trying to insert the image object) your `var ctx`is always taking the last one try to define it  every time in your loop -- take a look https://jsfiddle.net/cbchrL1g/2/

Comment: Ah fantastic please update as an answer. Thanks

Comment: I placed the comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop (while trying to insert the image object) your `var ctxis` is always taking the last one .

All you have to do is to define it every time in your loop:
take a look to [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbchrL1g/2)

Comment: Thanks mate I didn't even realise it.